# Selecting and hiding elements with Prototype or Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Anyone up for a Prototype challenge? I am new to Prototype and I am trying to do the following. Would do this in jQuery but the only js library installed is Prototype. Perhaps someone has a javascript solution that would work?

1. Strip any whitespace out of the form value (before and after)
2. If the input form length is 3 or less hide all the checkPrice.gif images in all rows.

Not sure if this is possible using Prototype.

```
<form method="get" id="searchForm" name="car" action="some-action">
<input type="text" value="Ford150" name="carPart" id="search" class="textContent">
</form>

<table border="1">
<tr>
<td class="description">Description:</td>
<td class="checkPrice"><p>Type:</p>
<p><a target="_blank" href="link.html"><img src="images/checkPrice.gif"></a></p>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="description">Description:</td>
<td class="checkPrice"><p>Type:</p>
<p><a target="_blank" href="link.html"><img src="images/checkPrice.gif"></a></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

- Rows repeat

Thanks so much to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean "If the input form value **length** is 3 or less" since the default input value is not a number.

```
function updateCheckPrice(event) {
    // $F() returns a string
    // String.strip() trims whitespace and returns a new string
    // String.length is a native property
    var length = $F(this).strip().length;

    // If length is 3 or less...
    var action = length <= 3 ? Element.hide : Element.show;

    // Pass the chosen show/hide function to every img element
    $$('img[src$=checkPrice.gif]').each(action);
}

document.observe('dom:loaded', function(){
    // Update as you type
    Event.observe('search', 'keyup', updateCheckPrice);
});
```

Comment: Thanks clockworkgeek! Yes sorry I meant if the length is 3 or less.

Comment: For some reason updateCheckPrice does not appear to be firing. It is supposed to fire once the dom is loaded right?

Comment: The function `updateCheckPrice` should fire on every keypress of the input field. It is wrapped in a `dom:loaded` event to make sure the field exists before trying to observe it. I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: I gave it a quick test and found that `keypress` doesn't work for backspaces and presumably other control keys too. I've fixed the answer code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Trim-function written in pure JS (from http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript):

```
function trim (str) {
var str = str.replace(/^\s\s*/, ''),
    ws = /\s/,
    i = str.length;
while (ws.test(str.charAt(--i)));
return str.slice(0, i + 1);
}
```

How to convert string to number: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/convert2.htm

How to access element's value using Prototype:
http://www.prototypejs.org/api/form/element/getValue

How to check is variable - string:

```
 function is_string(input){
    return typeof(input)=='string';
 }
```

How to hide element using Prototype:
http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/hide

Now you are ready to solve the task by yourself! ;)